# Should a beginner in ML use libraries like TF and Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, keras

As a beginner in ML field, should I in beginning implement various algorithms from scratch (using only NumPy for example) and then start using ML libraries like TensorFlow, Keras or vice-versa? For example, I implemented multilayer feed-forward neural network in Python using only NumPy but it took me few weeks to understand NNs at the level that I can implement them from scratch, would it be better that I spent that time to cover theory less thoroughly and use libraries to make more advanced models easily?

Comment: Doesn't it also depends on the time you have to learn building a NN? I think especially at such a complex topic like NN it is best to really understand  what you are doing, if you want to do it for a long time. If it is just a side projects for just a few month, how much time do you have to go into the depth before you have to present actual results?

Comment: I would love to use NN or AI alghorithms so its not side project.

Answer (score 1):

Start of by reading up on math/theory. For neural networks I can really recommend Michael Jensens free online book. All along he gives good python examples using only numpy. 
For DNNs, TF and Keras are IMO the easiest approach. For linear models, scikit learn would probably cover most.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the ML libraries because you will get stuff done. Ultimately something will go wrong and you will need to understand how the algorithms actually work. I highly recommend Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class on Coursera to help you fix any issues and obtain a deeper understanding of the algorithm. The class is worth the fee.